# Django auth.models User One-To-Many (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm new to django and my task is to make user able to create a lot profiles after registration when he's logged in.

This is my models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField( blank=False, max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField( blank=True, max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField( blank=True, max_length=100)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(blank=False, null=True, max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=False, max_length=100)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField( blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_addition = models.DateField(auto_now=True, editable=False, null=True)
```

When I create my user, do login and press create profile button I get :
**django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'user_id' cannot be null")**

This is my views.py:

```
    @login_required
def profile_create(request):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            profiles = Profile.objects.all()
            data['html_profile_list'] = render_to_string('basic_app/users_list_1_10.html', {'profiles': profiles})
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string('basic_app/partial_profile_create.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)


def register(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            registered = True
        else:
            print(user_form.errors)
    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
    return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html',{'user_form':user_form,'registered':registered})
```

This is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile

class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('name', 'lastname', 'city', 'country', 'phonenumber', 'email', 'date_of_birth')


class UserForm(ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    username = forms.CharField(help_text=False)

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should request user before saving ProfileForm:

```
@login_required
def profile_create(request):
    data = dict()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            add = form.save(commit=False)
            add.user = request.user
            add.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
            profiles = Profile.objects.all()
            data['html_profile_list'] = render_to_string('basic_app/users_list_1_10.html', {'profiles': profiles})
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()

    context = {'form': form}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string('basic_app/partial_profile_create.html', context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because in your `Profile` model you have `user` field which is `ForeignKey`. In Django `ForeignKey` is required by default, which means that you can't create new `Profile` without specifying `user` field. But you don't provide user in `ProfileForm`.

You can either provide user in `ProfileForm` or set `user` field as not required by adding:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Kamil, thanks for your attention. If I make `user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True` then I would get all db_users with their profiles shown in my datatables. But I'd like to show only profiles of the actual logged in user. And If I provide user in ProfileForm so I guess it would be a field with something to pass there when creating Profile, but I'd like it to be as only logged in user had the ability to create any number of profiles that would be connected to him with one-to-many relation. May be I should save profile to this user in ProfileForm, is it possible?